# Pass array from ajax to php in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Hi I'm trying to process an array in a php class by passing it through ajax.

I have read various tutorials that suggest using the JSON.stringify directive before the ajax call, but in doing so when I go to print an array, I saw that it is encoded as a string ...
How can I process it as an php array instead?

This is the code I used:
in js file:

```
let pw_script_vars = cc_object.ajax_url;
let pw_script_nonce = cc_object.itemNonce;

let lista_carte_finali =[18, 4, 12, 7, 16, 2, 3, 9, 1, 8];

let jsonString = JSON.stringify(lista_carte_finali);

function crea_tasto() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: pw_script_vars,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            action: 'carica_carte',
            nonce: pw_script_nonce,
            dati_carte: {dati_carte:jsonString}
        },
        success: function (dati_carte) {
            console.log(dati_carte);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('nessun dato');
        }
    });
}

$('#start_game').on('click', function () {
    crea_tasto();
})
```

mentre lato server ho :

```
public function carica_carte() {

        if (isset($_REQUEST)) {

            foreach($_REQUEST['dati_carte'] as $d){
                echo $d;
            }

        }

    die();

    }
```

Comment: its a bit confusing, you want to send an array to php via ajax? or you want to get an array from ajax response?

Answer (score 1):

```php
if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
  $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['dati_carte']));
  foreach($data as $d) {
    echo $d;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is my output [18,4,12,7,16,2,3,9,1,8]....so How can the function you have indicated be useful to me?

Comment: Here you can use JSON.stringify for converting this array to json in JS and then send data to Php function with using of Ajax, then you need to convert those Json data to Php array so you need to use json_encode function for converting json data to php array in php function where you get data from ajax to php.

Comment: If I don't ask too much, could you change the code I reported above?
I'm trying but if I change it I still have a PHP issue

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check now. You can this in your php function.

Comment: console report this with your code:{type: "warning", message: "stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given", file: "wp-content/plugins/giochi-carte/public/class-giochi-carte-public.php", line: 145, stack: Array(3), …}

Comment: Will you please check your jsonString variable at JS side with console log. Is it converted into string with slashes?, if not then please remove stripslashes from PHP function.